# Dynamically set properties from Dictionary<String, Any?> in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to set some properties on a class based on the values in a dictionary, at present I'm doing this:

```
let view: UIView = UIView()

if let hidden: Bool = self.props["hidden"] as? Bool {
  view.hidden = hidden
}

if let frame: CGRect = self.props["frame"] as? CGRect {
  self.uiInstance?.frame = frame
}

if let backgroundColor: UIColor = self.props["backgroundColor"] as? UIColor {
  self.uiInstance?.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
}
```

Which is fine with a few properties, but tiresome when it comes to large amounts. Is it possible in swift to do something like:

```
var view: UIView = UIView()

let config: Dictionary<String, Any?> = ["frame": CGRectZero, "backgroundColor": UIColor.whiteColor()]

for (key, value) in config {
  // view.??? = value
}
```

I'm aware there are could be risks of an error, if the `config` dictionary had something that didn't match an attribute on the UIView instance. e.g. `["text": "this is not going to work"]`. But aside from that, is it possible to dynamically set attributes on a class (like you can with some other languages, e.g. ruby's send - http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Object.html#method-i-send

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible with the `NSKeyValueCoding` method
[setValuesForKeysWithDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:) which calls `setValue:forKey:` for each key-value pair in the
dictionary:

```
let config: [String : AnyObject] = [
    "frame": NSValue(CGRect: CGRectZero),
    "hidden" : true,
    "backgroundColor": UIColor.whiteColor(),
    "autoresizingMask" : UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight.rawValue
]
self.view.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(config)
```

But note that all values must be Objective-C objects, which is why the frame
is wrapped into an `NSValue` object.
More about struct and scalar support in Key-Value Coding can be found
[here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/DataTypes.html).

Some types (such as `Bool`, `Int`) are automatically bridged to `NSNumber`, therefore
the `true` value for the hidden attribute needs not to be wrapped.
"options" such as `UIViewAutoresizing` must be converted to the underlying
integer value (which is then bridged to `NSNumber` automatically).

Comment: This looks perfect, thanks! Any idea how you would pass an enum (such as: `UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight`) in the same fashion. I can't seem to find a way of wrapping it in an NSValue.