# Swift dynamic property setting based on array keys

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I know a few questions already exist that seem to kinda cover what I'm asking (such as [Dynamically set properties from Dictionary<String, Any?> in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366840/dynamically-set-properties-from-dictionarystring-any-in-swift)), but this doesn't seem to be quite what I'm looking for.

Basically, I have a base object where I want to set the properties based on an object, like so:

```
init(data: Dictionary<String,String>)
{

    for (key, value) in data
    {
        //TODO set property as value here?
    }
}
```

I want to be able to pass a Dictionary in of keys/values and have them be dynamically added as properties of the object. I know that this behavior is possible in PHP, for example by doing `$this->{$key} = $value`, but I am somewhat unfamiliar with Swift so I haven't been able to figure out how to do this yet.

Also, if anybody could tell me the name of the functionality I'm trying to achieve here, that'd be really helpful. Not knowing what this concept is called is making searching for answers difficult :c

Comment: Do you want to add properties to the object *dynamically* based on the contents of the dictionary? Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25368820/is-it-possible-in-swift-to-add-variables-to-an-object-at-runtime ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I want to expand on the example given by @Okapi. If your class is a subclass of **NSObject**, then the **setValue:forKey:** and **valueForKey:** method are present by default. So, you could simply set your properties using the following code,

```
class Foo: NSObject {
    var x:String=""
    var y:String=""
    var z:String=""
    init(data: Dictionary<String,String>) {
        super.init()
        for (key,value) in data {
            self.setValue(value, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just out of curiosity, will `setValue:ForKey:` work for the x, y & z properties defined by the subclass? (will you have to override it?)

Comment: Sure but they have to be defined, otherwise it will crash.

Comment: Interesting. I suppose I can just extend NSObject with my classes and achieve the same behavior that I need.

Comment: The ideal, of course, is a way to do this without subclassing NSObject…

Comment: Thank you for clarifying my answer

Answer (score 1):

In your object define (or override) `setValue:forKey:`, then call this from you init method like so:

```
class Foo {
var x:String=""
var y:String=""
var z:String=""
init(data: Dictionary<String,String>) {
    for (key,value) in data {
        self.setValue(value, forKey: key)
    }
}
func setValue(value: AnyObject?, forKey key: String) {
    switch key {
    case "x" where value is String:
        self.x=value as String
    case "y" where value is String:
        self.y=value as String
    case "z" where value is String:
        self.z=value as String
    default:
        //super.setValue(value, forKey: key)
        return
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I was hoping to avoid explicitly setting the properties like you do in your setValue function. I know several languages (PHP, Java) have the ability to pass in dynamic key/value pairs and have them be mapped to the objects, so I'm hoping/assuming that such behavior will be available here too.